# Use Millennial Media without the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, ads, millennial-media

Is there anyway to use Millennial Media ads without the Video Player and (most importantly) the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VideoPlayer declaration in your manifest file has been deprecated since SDK version 5.1. It's no longer required. The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is technically optional but still highly recommended.

For direct answers to questions, I strongly suggest throwing in a support ticket at the Millennial website https://tools.mmedia.com/user/supportDevPortal .

Comment: If the app has no reason to use external storage, requesting the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission would be suspicious for users, so I don't consider adding it only for ads a good idea.

Comment: For a little more detail, if a user were to cache an interstitial ad while their internal storage were in use, Millennial could fail over to external storage when available. If you have an app that uses this permission anyway or if your app has a lot of permissions, it wouldn't hurt to keep this one.